# The Places API for iOS is not enabled in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api

[image]

I have enabled PlacesApi for same ApiKey still got error

> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS.

please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: I hope your key in the url is one you made up

Comment: @Scriptable who cares? If it is properly restricted (which you should do) you can publish it wherever you want. It's actually accessible on ANY website using the API.

Comment: So, you enabled the **Places API** and you use the **Directions API** and you don't understand why it doesn't work. Is that correct?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I find it best to not post possibly sensitive information. It may not be setup/restricted properly and could incur alot of usage charges. I don't find any issue in pointing this out to the OP

Comment: I agree that OP should be aware that he needs to restrict his API keys. But as I said, API keys are public on any website using one of their APIs. So the main point is: "restrict your keys" and not "don't post it anywhere" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your GooglePlaces version in your Podfile.

I was having the same issue and it works after updating the version in Podfile from 2.7.0 to 3.0.3

```
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '= 3.0.3'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker', '= 3.0.3'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '= 3.0.3'
```

> Installing GoogleMaps 3.0.3 (was 2.7.0)
>
> Installing GooglePlaces 3.0.3 (was 2.7.0)

Just noticed there's a [note](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) in the documentation which states:

> IMPORTANT: The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This
>   feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be
>   available after that date. **To continue using the Place Picker
>   through the deprecation period**, do NOT migrate to the new SDK yet,
>   and do NOT disable the Places SDK for iOS service in your Google Cloud
>   Platform project, as doing so will also disable the Place Picker.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your GoogleInfoPlist file and verify all credentials with your account.

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

**Match API key from GoogleInfoPlistFile**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really about programming anymore.

> The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (developers.google.com/places/ios/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS

It's clearly saying that the Places API is NOT enabled for that key. So you need to double check that the key is correct (copy/paste error?), that it is definitely enabled, try to generate a new API key on that account and try that.

You could also download sample apps for the places API and try your API key in there, but if it says it isn't enabled, it either isn't enabled on that account or the API key is wrong, it's not a code change, it's configuration