# The Places API for iOS is not enabled error

Tags: google-places-api

I'm not able to call the places API

> Error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API for iOS is
>   not enabled. See the developer's guide
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) for how to enable
>   the Google Places API for iOS.

I've followed this guide [Places API getting started](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start):

1) Install the API (Pod file and pod install)

2) Setup the API Key and restrict it to iOS

3) Add the key in AppDelegate (GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY"))

However, I'm still hitting the above-mentioned error.

***Is this the correct API to enable?***

[image]

I've waited for more than 30 mins (more than 17 hours now)for the API key settings to take effect but the error still persist. I'm able to use the same key to get Maps API to work though.

Version: "GooglePlaces (2.7.0)" + iOS12.0

Comment: i have the same  issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824375/the-places-api-for-ios-is-not-enabled-in-swift

Comment: if u got the solution please post answer here it will be helpful to me

Comment: Yes I've upvoted your question a few days back... Still couldn't figure out any way to solve it

Comment: I've tried the sample places project in objective-C and it works. @Swift You can try it using "pod try GooglePlaces" to check if your API key is valid. I need to check my swift code then...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works after updating the version in Podfile from 2.7.0 to 3.0.3

```
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '= 3.0.3'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker', '= 3.0.3'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '= 3.0.3'
```

> Installing GoogleMaps 3.0.3 (was 2.7.0)
>
> Installing GooglePlaces 3.0.3 (was 2.7.0)

Just noticed there's a note in the documentation which states:

> IMPORTANT: The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This
>   feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be
>   available after that date. **To continue using the Place Picker
>   through the deprecation period**, do NOT migrate to the new SDK yet,
>   and do NOT disable the Places SDK for iOS service in your Google Cloud
>   Platform project, as doing so will also disable the Place Picker.

Apparently it's not working now although it mentioned that it will be turned off on July 29, 2019. Perhaps I need to revert the code to use the prior version.