# Enabled Google Places ApiKey also Shows Can't load search results in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift4, google-places, gmsautocomplete

I have enabled Google Places Api from console which is same as my Google Maps ApiKey, and i have updated pod version from 2.7.0 to 3.0.3. and i have regenerated ApiKey also still i am not getting search results.
please help me to sort out this problem.

[Places Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcGyk.png)

[SearchResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3rkt.png)

**NOTE**: I tried all these solution but those are didn't works for me

[Can't load search results Google Places ios Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627648/cant-load-search-results-google-places-ios-swift)

[Google Places AutoComplete on iOS - Can't Load Search Results - Try Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165012/google-places-autocomplete-on-ios-cant-load-search-results-try-again)

The search result showes once in a 100 times after 1st search again its not showing any result. 
i don't understand why its happening like this. am i miss anything.

please someone help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: It would be useful for people to see a verifiable code example in order to help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: i don't think problem is really about programming because few days before it works fine, suddenly it behaves like this

Comment: @iosSwift did you solve this problem ? if yes please let me know.

Comment: i have same problem, if you solved it ,help me

Comment: @RehamMokhtar, i have followed these steps, and it worked for me, please have look this maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910046/the-places-api-for-ios-is-not-enabled-error/54976605#54976605